# Can I still visit the UK if my UAE work visa expires shortly after I enter?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, working-visas

My UAE work visa is about to expire on September 30 of this year, but my UK tourist visa is still valid until November. Can I still travel to the UK in September?

Comment: Are you still working in the UK and have just been away on a short trip, or has your job finished and you no longer live in the UK?

Comment: Sorry I have a tourist visa for uk which is valid till nov.but my working visa here in uae is valid only till sept.30

Answer (score 2):

It could be a problem. You were given the visa when you had a job to go back to in UAE. Without the job there, border control in UK might decide you are likely to look for work in UK and refuse to allow you entry. But this is not certain and depends on your overall circumstances and landing interview.